# Have a query about if condition in batch as my below snippet of code doesn't work

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

```
for %%a in ("a.txt") do set length=%%~za

if %length% gtr 0  
(
findstr /lv /g:a.txt refer.txt >> finalres.txt
)
```

I am unable to run the above piece of code it says syntax is not correct.
Basically I have a reference file and another file by name "a.txt".
If the filesize of a.txt is greater than 0 then both a.txt and refer.txt should be compared and all those entries which are not common in both the files should be appended to finalres.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open-parenthesis MUST be on the same line as the `if`

Answer (score 2):

.. or you put a caret `^`  at the end of the line before the single open parenthesis.